# The mod_negotiation seems to be enabled, but .php files without extensions return 404

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, http-status-code-404

I have the following problem - after moving to a new platform PHP files aren't found unless URL contains their extension. So, if `/var/www` contains file `problem.php`, the URL `http://localhost/problem.php` displays correctly, but `http://localhost/problem` does not. I have tried the following:

- Checked if `MultiViews` are enabled in the configuration file:

  ```
  <Directory /var/www/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
  </Directory>
  ```
- Checked if `mod_negotiation` is loaded via `phpinfo()`:

> Loaded Modules: core mod_log_config mod_logio mod_version prefork http_core mod_so mod_alias mod_auth_basic mod_authn_file mod_authz_default mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_deflate mod_dir mod_env mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_php5 mod_reqtimeout mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_status

- Just in case the above was a stress-induced hallucination, tried loading the `mod_negotiation2` and restarting the server:

  ```
  leviathan www # a2enmod negotiation
  Module negotiation already enabled
  leviathan www # service apache2 restart
    Restarting web server apache2                                                                                             apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
   ... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
                                                                                                                        [ OK ]
  leviathan www #
  ```
- Made sure `.htaccess` isn't causing this by testing in a directory without `.htaccess` file.

But all for naught, and I still get 404 errors, and I completely fail to understand why. What am I doing wrong? My platform is Linux Mint 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. Add the following line into the `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mime.conf`:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .html .htm
```

Then restart apache with:

```
# service apache2 restart
```

And it's done. I suppose it's a bug in Linux Mint's configuration.

Source: ["Serving pages without PHP file extension [apache]" thread on webdeveloper.com forum](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?59933-Serving-pages-without-PHP-file-extension-apache)